# DC to DC converter options

Tags: dc-dc-converter, converter, step-down, step-up

I'm admitting here that I'm a little out of my element, so take that into consideration.

I am working on a project that combines a few different electrical devices that use different DC power sources. To try and simplify and reduce the number of AC to DC plugs needed, I'm hoping I can just do some creative converting. Two lamps need output power of 12V 1A DC. The other device (light strip) has a power requirement of 24V 0.83A.

Is there some sort of converter I could use to either step up the light strip or step down the two lamps and just power them all from a single plug?

One of the other options would possibly be to convert AC directly to those DC power requirements, but I suspect that might be a little more difficult ultimately.

[image: Proposed Configuration]

Comment: Buck or boost converter as appropriate.  Alternatively, if the two 12v lamps are identical, put them in series and use 24v for everything.

Comment: There are converters which will step up a voltage (boost converters) say from 12V to 24V, and there are converters which will step down a voltage (buck converters) say from 24V to 12V.

Comment: Yeah, I've found converters for stepping up or stepping down, but nothing which matches the amperage needed that I've been able to find.  I do seem to remember something about more amperage being ok for some electronics than less (ie. 2A for something that only requires 1A is ok), but my memory on that fact is a little fuzzy so I don't trust it to be accurate.

Comment: What do you have for available power at either 12V or 24V?

Comment: I've got a power supply with 24V 0.83A and two with 12V 1A.  If I need to get something that will work a little better overall I can buy one. I just am not sure which option is the most efficient at this point.

Comment: And actually, the more I read, the more I suspect my "fact" to be accurate.  So with three devices that originally had available amperage output of just shy of 3A, if i get a DC brick that has 3A output and either 12V or 24V, I can use a buck or boost converter and power all three devices from one supply.  Are my suspicions accurate?

Comment: You need a 24v supply capable of at least 2 amps, or a 12v supply capable of at least 4 amps, preferably more since the converter will not be 100% efficient.  The buck or boost converter has to be similarly rated for enough current.

Comment: Added a very quick and dirty diagram of the proposed configuration to the original post.  So 24V 2A stepped down to 12V as long as it handles 2A or more is ok?  Is my logic correct?

Comment: To be honest, I think your diagram is a bit confusing.

Comment: Totally fair.  I'm just trying to come up with what the layout should look like in a very rough sense.  Do I need to have two separate buck converters?  One for each lamp?

Comment: No, you don't need two buck converters. What confused me in your diagram is that you have what I think are lamps, but they have the labels "orignal PS" next to them. Can you easily remove those labels?

Comment: Sorry, yeah  Original PS = Original Power Supply.  I can yank those out though.  And yes, those are the lamps drawn in Paint.  It's updated now.

Comment: The lamps take 1 Amp at 12V. The original power supplies have nothing to do with the circuit you want.

Comment: Very good. Thanks.

Comment: So, you have your circuit, do you still have questions?

Comment: Nope, so long as that power brick and the buck will work as I have them in the diagram I should be good.